# Read and write utf8 string in microsoft local database

Tags: c#, utf-8, visual-studio-2013, local-database

I am writing a WindowsForm application. I am using Visual Studio local database.
Every thing is OK, but if I write some UTF8 content in forms, after saving and getting the content again it shows in this form "????".
I think there is problem with database, but I don't know how to configure database to store utf8 content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field in the database needs to be an nvarchar instead of a varchar.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you save your information to database, if it is inline sql then prefix your content with N'yourvalue'.